# Simulate touch drag with mouse

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In flutter 2.2, you could use mouse to swipe up and down on a `ListView`. It would act like swiping by finger on touch screens. However in version 2.5 this seems to have been removed and now clicking won't do what touch does, for example over-scrolling a `BouncingScrollPhysics` (something I'm relying on in my app).

Is there any way to re-enable the simulation functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions the mouse drag ability has been removed on scrollable widgets however you can enable it in two ways.

First you need to create this class:

```dart
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
    PointerDeviceKind.touch,
    PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
  };
}
```

Then enable it in your app like this:

#### 1. Enabling it on just one widget

Wrap your scrollable inside a `ScrollConfiguration` and set the `behavior`:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
  child: ListView(
    ...
  )
)
```

#### 2. Enabling it appwide

In your `MaterialApp` set the `scrollBehavior`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
  ...
)
```

**TIP:** If you have multiple nested `MaterialApp`s, you have to set `scrollBehavior` on all of them.

[Reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag)